# Windows 7 won’t boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

After installing Magic Disc, my Windows 7 64-bit installation won't boot normally or in safe mode.

At the moment I'm not sure what was causing the problem, but since it was full of things that I did not use and it was slow, I decided to reinstall a fresh Windows 7. Then after installing drivers and some software, I  reinstalled Magic Disc, it was working, and I used it to mount some iso files.

When I rebooted, I got the same problem as before, Windows won't boot.

In Normal mode it just hangs at the animated logo, and in safe mode it hangs when loading `CLASSPNP.SYS`

I tried the repair tool from the DVD, tried chdsk, but it didn't solve the problem..

I don't want to reinstall again, so is there something that i can do to solve the issue?

I am pretty sure the problem is caused by Magic Disc. It create a Virtual DVD drive, so there are drivers involved, and this is the only thing that I installed before I got this problem.

But how I can remove it if I cannot boot even in safe mode?

I have a working OS X (hackintosh) installation on the same hard drive, if that can help..

Comment: @gronostaj If you read well my question, you will notice that i said that it won't boot even in safe mode. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I guess I'm too tired to answer questions ;)

Comment: One more attempt: try booting Mini XP from Hiren's Boot CD. When it boots up, run a program called Autoruns, it will let you connect to remote system. Choose your local OS's registry hive. Then look for any drivers associated with Magic Disc and uncheck them.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by manually deleting all the drivers/files related to Magic Disk from OS X.

Comment: Which files were they?

Comment: same problem here!  I'm 80% sure MagicDisc is the problem!  I have access to the filesystem via Debian Live, but not sure which files to delete.

Comment: Related: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/247344-49-magicdisc-install-driver-error-boot

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to boot by getting windows to load "last known good configuration". (F8 during startup => select "Load last known good configuration".

Then uninstalled the piece of junk.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but i believe i had the exact same issue today. Happened to install magicdisk earlier today and then a few hours later my pc would not get past the windows logo screen, tried safeboot and it kept getting stuck at apmwin.sys. Startup repair wouldn't do it either and my restore points threw errors (0x80070005).

Luckily i tried last known good configuration using F8 at boot and it seems to have fixed it.

Tried installing magicdisk again and exactly the same thing has happened so i'm pretty sure this is the culprit.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Run into same issue, what helped me was to remove the following file `Windows\System32\drivers\mcdbus.sys`.